# longtable in HTML has stretched lines after compiling one more time in tex4ht

Tags: longtable, tex4ht

I've seen this problem for long time and never really could figure why it happens.

Given this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}    

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1in}|p{.4in}|p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|}
\caption{My nice table}\\ \hline  
Type of ODE& {\small Count} &Mathematica & Maple\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename \thetable{} Percentage solved per Maple ODE type -- continued from previous page}\\\hline 
Type of ODE& {\small Count} &Mathematica & Maple\\ \hline 
\endhead \hline 
\multicolumn{4}{|r|}{Continued on next page}\\\hline 
\endfoot \hline 
\endlastfoot         
A&429&100.00\%&100.00\%\\\hline 
C&127&100.00\%&100.00\%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex gives

[image]

Deleting any `foo.*` in the folder (except foo.tex ofcourse) and compiling using `make4ht` gives

```
>rm foo.*
rm: remove regular file 'foo.4ct'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.4tc'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.aux'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.css'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.dvi'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.htm'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.idv'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.lg'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.log'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.pdf'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.tex'? n
rm: remove regular file 'foo.tmp'? y
rm: remove regular file 'foo.xref'? y
make4ht  -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "htm,mathjax"
```

[image]

Which is good. No stretched lines.

Here is the strange thing. When compiling again, no matter how many times, but without deleting all intermediate files as above, gives stretched lines now

```
make4ht  -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "htm,mathjax"
```

[image]

Should not compiling the latex file each time give the same output regardless of what intermediate files happened to be in the folder? I checked this in Firefox and Edge and Chrome.

What to do to make sure compiling gives same output as the first one above in HTML without the need to delete all the intermediate files each time? This problem does not show up with `lualatex`.

ps. I understand that some intermediate files can be used (.aux for example) if present in the folder from last compilation. By why repeated compilation does not fix this issue then?  It is only when the folder is empty, I get correct output first time only.

TL 2022

Comment: Possible source of your problem can be a way how you set captions for table parts after the first one. Doe to it your table is wide than text width. Replace it by `\caption[]{Percentage solved per Maple ODE type -- continued from previous page} \\ `  and see if you still have problems at conversion to `html`

Comment: @Zarko you mean to change `\caption{My nice table}\\ \hline` to `\caption[]{My nice table}\\ \hline`? The line just below `\begin{longtable}`? I just did. No effect at all.  Same result. It is a mystery why the stretched lines do not show up first time, but second time they show up.

Comment: No, I mean the second caption in `longtable`, which is emulated by  `multicolumn` cells . So try `\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1in}| l |p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|}
\caption{My nice table} \\ \hline
Type of ODE & {Count} &  Mathematica & Maple     \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Percentage solved per Maple ODE type -- continued from previous page} \\
    \hline
Type of ODE & {Count} &  Mathematica & Maple     \\
    \hline
\endhead ` .

Comment: I did read your comment twice. I thought you meant the caption line. I have no caption other than the one just below `\begin{longtable}` But I just replaced `\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename \thetable{} Percentage solved per Maple ODE type -- continued from previous page}\\\hline`  by `\caption[]{Percentage solved per Maple ODE type -- continued from previous page} \\` and this had no effect at all. same result as before. If this is not what you meant, may be you could post the complete code of what you mean I need to change.

Comment: @Zarko I tried it. No change. Here is the complete MWE. `\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1in}| l |p{1.5in}|p{1.5in}|} \caption{My nice table} \\ \hline Type of ODE & {Count} &  Mathematica & Maple     \\      \hline \endfirsthead \caption[]{Percentage solved per Maple ODE type -- continued from previous page} \\     \hline Type of ODE & {Count} &  Mathematica & Maple     \\     \hline \endhead 
\multicolumn{4}{|r|}{Continued on next page}\\\hline 
\endfoot \hline 
\endlastfoot         
A&429&100.00\%&100.00\%\\\hline 
C&127&100.00\%&100.00\%
\end{longtable} \end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one instance where the number of compilations matters. As you have four columns in the table, it needs four compilations before joined cells are correct. Internally, `\caption` in Longtable joins cells in a row, so it appears as one line. Once the cell structure is correct, the CSS instructions that draw borders around table columns take place.

To fix this issue, we need to change HTML code that is created for `\caption` in Longtable. I will fix it in TeX4ht sources. In the meantime, you can use the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\AddToHook{env/longtable/begin}{
\Configure{caption}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<caption>}\par\ShowPar\HCode{<span class="id">}}{:\ }{\HCode{</span><span class="content">}}{\HCode{</span>}\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</caption>}}
}
\Css{caption .id{font-weight:bold;}}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
    \cptA: #1{\cap:ref{#2}}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\cptB:\fi\cptC:#3\cptD:
    \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip
}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It does two things: it configures `\caption` to produce `<caption>` tags inside `longtable` instead of the default `<figcaption>`. The second is a redefinition of `\LT@makecaption` that omits code that produced spurious table cells.

This is the result:

[image]